# How to go to URL with parameters

Tags: javascript

How would i do the following in javascript?

Do a `GET` call to a URL, with additional parameter .e.g.

I want to do `GET` to http://test with parameter myid = 5.

Thanks,
Boots

Answer (score 3):

try something like:

```
location.replace('http://test.com/sometest.html?myid=5&someotherid=6');
```

or

```
location.href = 'http://test.com/sometest.html?myid=5&someotherid=6';
```

Answer (score 3):

If by *"Do a 'GET' call to a url"* you mean to change the current location to a certain url, all you have to do is assign the new url to the `location` variable:

```
var newUrl = "http://test";
window.location = newUrl;
```

If you want to construct the url by adding some query parameters, you can do :

```
newUrl += "?myid=" + myid;
```

In addition, you can use a function to map the parameters to the url :

```
function generateUrl(url, params) {
    var i = 0, key;
    for (key in params) {
        if (i === 0) {
            url += "?";
        } else {
            url += "&";
        }
        url += key;
        url += '=';
        url += params[key];
        i++;
    }
    return url;
}
```

And then you could use it as :

```
window.location = generateUrl("http://test",{ 
    myid: 1,
    otherParameter: "other param value"
});
```

obs: this function only works for int/bool/string variables in the params object. Objects and arrays cannot be used in this form.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just include it normally in the query string: `http://test?myid=5&otherarg=3`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myid = 5;
window.location = "http://test?myid=" + myid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to call it. And **don't go to it**:
Use an AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://test/?myid=5'
});
```

Here in jQuery. But there are enough non-jQuery examples on the internet.